# Как отформатировать ввод?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, поток-ввода

Есть такой код,при работе и int,если введу 234sds,считывает 234,а мне необходимо,чтобы выдавало ошибку.

```
int a = 0;
        char answer;
        do
        {
            do {
                system("cls");
                cin.clear();
                _flushall();
                cout << "1.Add" << endl;
                cout << "2.Delete Node" << endl;
                cout << "3.Delete All" << endl;
                cout << "4.Show content of tree" << endl;
                cout << "5.Write to txt file" << endl;
                cout << "6.Read from txt file" << endl;
                cout << "7.Write to binary file" << endl;
                cout << "8.Read from binary file" << endl;
                a=e->type();
            } while (!cin.good() || a < 1 || a>8);

            switch (a)
            {
            case 1:cin >> value; tree.Add(value); break;//добавить
            case 2:cin >> value; tree.Delete(value);  break; //делитнуть
            case 3:tree.Delete();break;//массив делитнуть
            case 4:tree.Show(); break;
            case 5:fileTxt.Write(tree); break;
            case 6:fileTxt.ReadEndFile(); break;
            case 7:fileBinary.Write(tree); break;
            case 8:fileBinary.ReadEndFile(); break;
            }
            if (!cin)
            {
                cout << "Error";                
            }
            cin.clear(); // на случай, если предыдущий ввод завершился с ошибкой
            cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
            _flushall();
            cout << "contiue (y/n)" << endl;
            cin >> answer;
        }while(answer == 'y');
    }
```

Comment: уточните вопрос.

Comment: @Alex.B Когда ввожу 234fd,компилятор считает,что я ввел 234 и продолжает работу будто бы все хорошо,но мне нужно,чтобы все-таки он говорил,что есть ошибки(я проверяю !cin,но этого видимо не достаточно)

Comment: Так. Смотрите конструкция !cin говорит о том что если не введено то ошибка у вас соответственно данные вводятся. для обработки неверной строки используйте ф-ю getline и разбирайте(обрабатывайте ), то что вы прочитали из консоли. Ситуация при которой у вас буквы отбрасываются говорит о то что вы читайте в целочисленный тип и он не предусмотрен для символов отличных от цифр.

Comment: @Alex.В спасибо